# Find all possible real 2x2 matrices A

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find all possible real $2×2$ matrices $A$ such that $A^{2019} = \begin{bmatrix}
     0 &  1 \\
    -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

I am really stuck with this one, could someone provide some insight to help me solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
z &t \end{bmatrix}$. Then
$$\begin{bmatrix}
     0 &  1 \\
    -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
z &t \end{bmatrix}=A^{2019}A=AA^{2019}=\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
z &t \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
     0 &  1 \\
    -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
     z &  t \\
    -x & -y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
     -y &  x \\
    -t & z
\end{bmatrix}$$
This implies $z=-y$ and $t=x$, and hence $A$ must be of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\
-y &x \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, identify $A$ with a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

We may identify $$ \begin {bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}$$ with the complex number $$a+bi$$

Thus the matrix $$ \begin {bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ will be identified with $i$

The problem is finding all $2019$ complex numbers $z$ such  that $$z^{2019}=i=e^{i \pi /2 }$$

These are $$\cos (\theta_k ) + i \sin (\theta_k)$$ for $$\theta_k = \frac {\pi/2 +2k\pi }{2019}$$ for $k=0,1,2,...,2018$

The matrices then are $$ \begin {bmatrix}\cos \theta_k&\sin \theta_k\\-\sin \theta_k&\cos \theta_k\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Why are you assuming that $A$ has that particular form?

Comment: We are talking about roots of $i$

Comment: The question is asking to find all such $A$. You are assuming that $A$ has that given form... Note that $\begin{bmatrix} 2 &1 \\ -3 &-2\end{bmatrix}^2=I_2$ but that matrix is NOT a corresponding to a complex root of unity.... The fact that $A^{2019}$ corresponds to a complex number, doesn't necessarily mean that $A$ corresponds to a complex number, if it does you need to prove it.

Comment: You are correct, I should have proved that the solutions have that particular form. Thanks for your informative comment.

Comment: In particular, does it also work to identify $ \begin {bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ with $-i$ instead of with $i$?  And if it does, do you get any additional solutions?